# How to exclude specific class from a Maven dependency ( Jar dependency) at runtime

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

How to exclude specific class from a Maven dependency ( Jar dependency).

I have an issue with ObjectUtils.class from avro-tools.jar which is picked in run time that does not have method which is used from commons-lang3 jar. Which causing runtime NoSuchMethod error.

I wanted to know is there any way i can specify in my pom.xml to exclude this class org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils from avro-tools.jar (1.9.1) version and pick it from commons-lang3.jar (3.9 version)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of your project structure and the problem you have. Also include the POM file of your project.

Comment: You can not exclude a single class which is contained within a dependency. The only thing you can do in such cases is define a version for commons-lang directly in your own project which overrules the dependency...but that might cause other issues....may be you have to use other versions. But it looks like the avro-tools.jar have shaded the commons-lang3 part which is really bad but can't be changed. You should contact the author ...

Answer (score -2):

try maven-shade-plugin,it will remove class from final jar generated by pom.xml

Note :- Removing particular class from jar is not possible.

```
     <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>TestShadeProfile</id>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                            <filters>
                             <filter>
                                <artifact>org.apache.avro:avro-tools</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                             </filter>
                            </filters>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

hope it will help you

mvn clean package -P TestShadeProfile

Comment: Hi Sarjit, thanks for your reply. let me try and reply back

Comment: No Sarjit, same issue , i dont see  that class is not exclued form the jar when its downloaded the dependencies

Comment: Exclusions only working on dependency which means in other words on the jar which is defined as a dependency. You can't exclude a single class.

Comment: Updated the solution using maven-shade-plugin