# Exclude a specific class from Maven dependency at runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am working with a Spring Boot application, where I have added one dependency in pom.xml, but I would like to remove one specific class from one of the dependencies as follows:

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.anotherapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-commons</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalOptions>
                        <additionalOption>-Xdoclint:none</additionalOption>
                    </additionalOptions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>com.anotherapp:java-commons</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>src/main/java/com/anotherapp/exception/TcInternalExceptionAspect.*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>
                                        com.myapp.MainClass
                                    </mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>target/classes/static/</directory>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-info</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plug>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Here, in this project, as you can see in the above pom, I would like to exclude the class: `TcInternalExceptionAspect` from the dependency `java-commons`. As recommended in a few posts here, I included the `shade` plugin.

But, after the build is complete, I am still able to see the `TcInternalExceptionAspect` class in the final jar file. I am not able to understand, what I am missing here.

In this context, I have gone through this: [How to exclude specific class from a Maven dependency ( Jar dependency) at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59537306/how-to-exclude-specific-class-from-a-maven-dependency-jar-dependency-at-runti), but it did not help.

Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Comment: Try removing `src/main/java/` from the start of the excluded class.

Comment: Can you please share your requirement why you want to do this?

Comment: Based on your configuration this is a class which you have added to your project.. If you don't like to have it there.. just simply remove it... furthermore based on the given spring-boot-maven-plugin it does not makes sense to use maven-shade-plugin use the spring-boot-maven-plugin instead...